# Parametric classes in python

Tags: python

I want to define a pair of classes that are almost identical, except that the class methods are decorated in two different ways.  Currently, I just have a factory function that takes the decorator as an argument, constructs the class using that decorator, and returns the class.  Greatly simplified, something like this works:

```py
# Defined in mymodule.py

def class_factory(decorator):
    class C:
        @decorator
        def fancy_func(self, x):
            # some fanciness
            return x
    return C

C1 = class_factory(decorator1)
C2 = class_factory(decorator2)
```

And I can use these as usual:

```py
import mymodule

c1 = mymodule.C1()
c2 = mymodule.C2()
```

I'm not entirely comfortable with this, for a number of reasons.  First, a purely aesthetic reason: the types of both objects display as `mymodule.class_factory.<locals>.C`.  They're not actually identical, but they look like it, and it causes problems with the documentation.  Second, my class is pretty complicated.  I'd actually like to use inheritance and mixins and so on, but in any case, those other classes also need access to the decorators.  So currently, I make several factories, and call the parent class factories inside the child class factory, and the child inherits from the parents created in this way.  But this means I can't really use the resulting parents as classes outside the factory.

So my questions are

1. Is there a better design pattern for this sort of thing?  It would be really convenient if there were some way to use inheritance, where the decorators are actually methods in a class, and I inherit in two different ways.
2. Is there anything wrong with changing the `<locals>` part of the class name by just altering `C.__qualname__` before returning?

---

To be a bit more specific: I want one version of the class to work extremely quickly with numpy arrays, and I want another version of the class to work with arbitrary python objects — especially sympy expressions.  So for the first, I decorate with `@numba.guvectorize` (and relatives).  This means I actually need to pass numba some signatures, so I can't just rely on numba falling back to object mode for the second case.  But for simplicity, I think we can ignore the issue of signatures here.  For the second case, I basically make a no-op decorator that ignores signatures and does nothing to the function.

Comment: I don't think altering `__qualname__` is particularly problematic. Might cause some issues with pickling? I'm going to think about a good solution for question 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach using `__init_subclass__`. I use keyword arguments here, but you could easily change it so the decorators are defined as methods on `C1` and `C2` and are applied in `__init_subclass__`.

```
def passthru(f):
    return f

class BaseC:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, /, decorator=passthru, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        # if you also have class attributes or methods you don't want to decorate,
        # you might need to maintain an explicit list of decoratable methods
        for attr in dir(cls):
            if not attr.startswith('__'):
                setattr(cls, attr, decorator(getattr(cls, attr)))
    def fancy_func(self, x):
        # some fanciness
        return x

def two(f):
    return lambda self, x: "surprise"

class C1(BaseC):
    pass

class C2(BaseC, decorator=two):
    pass

print(C1().fancy_func(42))
print(C2().fancy_func(42))

# further subclassing
class C3(C2):
    pass

print(C3().fancy_func(42))
```

Comment: Ooh, I didn't know about `__init_subclass__`!  I'll just think about this for a while.

Comment: Thanks very much @Jasmijn.  I took your example and expanded it for my particular needs, but this is really the answer to the question I posed.  I think it's actually a pretty elegant approach.

Answer (score 0):

I took @Jasmijn's suggestion of using `__init_subclass__`.  But since I really need multiple decorators (jit, guvectorize, and sometimes neither even when using numba with other methods), I tweaked it a little.  Rather than jitting every public method, I use decorators to flag methods with attributes explaining how to compile them.

I decorate the individual methods much like I would have originally, indicating whether to `jit` or whatnot.  But these decorators don't actually do any compilation; they just add hidden attributes to the functions indicating whether and how to apply the actual decorators.  Then, when a subclass is created, `__init_subclass__` loops through, looking for these attributes on all the subclass's methods, and applying any requested compilation.

I turn this into a pretty general class, named `Jitter` below.  Any class that wants the option of jitting in multiple ways can just inherit from this class and decorate methods with `Jitter.jit` or `Jitter.guvectorize`.  By default, nothing much happens to those functions, so the first child class of Jitter can be used with sympy, for example.  But I can also inherit from such a class while adding the relevant keyword(s) to the class definition, enabling jitting in the subclass.  Here's the `Jitter` class:

```py
class Jitter:
    def jit(f):
        f._jit = True
        return f

    def guvectorize(*args, **kwargs):
        def wrapper(f):
            f._guvectorize = (args, kwargs)
            return f
        return wrapper

    def __init_subclass__(cls, /, jit=None, guvectorize=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        for attr_name in dir(cls):
            attr = getattr(cls, attr_name)
            if jit is not None and hasattr(attr, '_jit'):
                setattr(cls, attr_name, jit(attr))
            elif guvectorize is not None and hasattr(attr, '_guvectorize'):
                args, kwargs = getattr(attr, '_guvectorize')
                setattr(cls, attr_name, guvectorize(*args, **kwargs)(attr))
```

Now, I can inherit from this class very conveniently:

```py
import numba as nb


class Adder(Jitter):
    @Jitter.jit
    def add(x, y):
        return x + y


class NumbaAdder(Adder, jit=nb.njit):
    pass
```

Here, `Adder.add` is a regular python function that just happens to have a `_jit` attribute, but `NumbaAdder.add` is a numba jit function.  For more realistic code, I would use the same `Jitter` class and the same `NumbaAdder` class, but would put all the complexity into the `Adder` class.

Note that we *could* decorate with `Adder.jit`, but this would be precisely the same as decorating with `Jitter.jit`, because `Adder.jit` doesn't get changed (if at all) until after the decorators in the class definition have already been applied, so we still need to loop through and apply the jit functions with `__init_subclass__`.